# How to Include Something Like &trade; in a Sitemap

Tags: php, xml, sitemap

I'm trying to generate a sitemap using php, and I'm getting errors because some of my product names include "&trade".

I know that & needs to be escaped to &amp, but I'm unsure what to do with &trade.  This is a hard problem to search for, I'm certain its come up for someone, but I can't find something relevant.

```
// Remove Whitespace from Links
function url_safe ($data) {
    $data = preg_replace('/\s/', '-', htmlentities($data));
    return $data;       
}

//URLs for Products
$query = "SELECT product_id, product_name FROM product WHERE active = 'Y'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die(mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br />Query: ' . $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data .= "\t<url>\n";
    $data .= "\t\t<loc>https://www.example.com/product.php?pid=$row[0]&amp;name=" . url_safe($row[1]) . "</loc>\n";
    $data .= "\t\t<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>\n";
    $data .= "\t\t<priority>1.0</priority>\n";
    $data .= "\t</url>\n";
    $i++;
}
```

This is the error I get for any product that has &trade in the title.

XML Parsing Error: undefined entity

Here is an example from the output generated that is causing an error.

```
    <url>
    <loc>https://www.example.com/product.php?pid=2738&amp;name=My-Product&trade;-Has-A-Trademark</loc>
    <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
    </url>
```

Comment: It needs to be encoded as `&amp;trade;`... maybe replace `&amp;` with `&` then use `<loc>" . htmlspecialchars('.....') . '</loc>'` because this is for XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `urlencode`.

> This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL, as a convenient way to pass variables to the next page.

Maintaining most of your original code, your result should look something like this:

```
// Remove Whitespace from Links
function url_safe ($data) {
    $data = preg_replace('/\s/', '-', htmlentities($data));

    // Adding url encoding
    $data = urlencode($data);

    return $data;       
}

//URLs for Products
$query = "SELECT product_id, product_name FROM product WHERE active = 'Y'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die(mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br />Query: ' . $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data .= "\t<url>\n";
    $data .= "\t\t<loc>https://www.example.com/product.php?pid=$row[0]&amp;name=" . url_safe($row[1]) . "</loc>\n";
    $data .= "\t\t<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>\n";
    $data .= "\t\t<priority>1.0</priority>\n";
    $data .= "\t</url>\n";
    $i++;
}
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php for more reading.

Comment: When I add the code I ended up with something like this: /product.php?pid=4409&amp;name=My-Product%26amp%3Btrade%3B-Has-A-Trademark  Will this work for my XML sitemap?

Comment: Adding the code worked, and Google recognizes the sitemap with no errors.

Answer (score 2):

XML does not support named entities like `&trade;` only (X)HTML has them. (or other XML based formats that define them.)

Here are two solutions for special characters. You can just define the XML as UTF-8 and use the character directly or you can use numeric entities.

Here is an example what DOM does:

```
$document = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$document
    ->appendChild($document->createElement('foo'))
    ->textContent = '™';
echo $document->saveXML();    

$document = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'ASCII');
$document
    ->appendChild($document->createElement('foo'))
    ->textContent = '™';
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<foo>™</foo> 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?> 
<foo>&#8482;</foo>
```

You can see that in an UTF-8 encoded XML it uses the character while with ASCII encoding it encodes it as a numeric entity.

Your example is a little different, because you put variables into the query string of an URL. So you have to encode them for that first and after that the URL for an XML text node. The functions to encode variables for an URL are `urlencode()` and `rawurlencode()`. I like to use `sprintf()` for readability. Here is an example for building the URLs:

```
$data = [
    [1, 'foo'],
    [2, 'foo ™'],
    [3, 'foo & bar'],
];

foreach ($data as $item) {
    $url = sprintf(
        'https://www.example.com/product.php?pid=%s&name=%s',
        urlencode($item[0]), 
        urlencode($item[1])
    );
    echo $url, "\n"; 
}
```

Output:

```
https://www.example.com/product.php?pid=1&name=foo 
https://www.example.com/product.php?pid=2&name=foo+%E2%84%A2 
https://www.example.com/product.php?pid=3&name=foo+%26+bar
```

You're creating the XML as TEXT, but PHP implements an XMLWriter for exactly this job. Using the API will take care of character with special meaning in XML - like the `&` used to separate the URL parameters.

```
$data = [
    [1, 'foo'],
    [2, 'foo ™'],
    [3, 'foo & bar'],
];

$writer = new XMLWriter();
$writer->openURI('php://stdout');

$writer->setIndent(1);
$writer->setIndentString("\t");
$writer->startDocument();
$writer->startElementNS(NULL, 'urlset', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9');

foreach ($data as $item) {
  $writer->startElement('url');
  $writer->writeElement(
        'loc', 
        sprintf(
            'https://www.example.com/product.php?pid=%s&name=%s',
            urlencode($item[0]), 
            urlencode($item[1])
        )
  );
  $writer->writeElement('changefreq', 'monthly');
  $writer->writeElement('priority', '1.0');
  $writer->endElement();
}

$writer->endElement();
$writer->endDocument();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"> 
  <url>
    <loc>https://www.example.com/product.php?pid=1&amp;name=foo</loc>
    <changefreq>monthly</changefreq> 
    <priority>1.0</priority> 
  </url> 
  <url> 
    <loc>https://www.example.com/product.php?pid=2&amp;name=foo+%E2%84%A2</loc> 
    <changefreq>monthly</changefreq> 
    <priority>1.0</priority> 
  </url> 
  <url> 
    <loc>https://www.example.com/product.php?pid=3&amp;name=foo+%26+bar</loc> 
    <changefreq>monthly</changefreq> 
    <priority>1.0</priority> 
  </url> 
</urlset>
```